# Deploy Solution via DevOps Pipelines with secret environment variable

Tags: power-platform, azure-devops

I am deploying a Power Platform solution using pipelines in DevOps. Part of this is to supply the release with a JSON settings file for each environment so, for example, when you deploy to test, it will point towards a test SharePoint site, and when you deploy to UAT, it will point to UAT SharePoint Site.

Example:

```
{
  "EnvironmentVariables": [
    {
      "SchemaName": "SharePointSite",
      "Value": "[SharePoint Site ID]"
    },
    {
      "SchemaName": "List1",
      "Value": "[SharePoint List 1 ID]"
    },
    {
      "SchemaName": "List2",
      "Value": "[SharePoint List 2 ID]"
    }
]
}
```

Most of the environment variable are self explanatory passing either text values or IDs for various SharePoint sites, but how do you pass a value for a **Secret Environment Variable** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/environmentvariables#use-azure-key-vault-secrets-preview)?

When creating a secret EV, you need to provide the Azure Subscription ID, Resource Group Name, Azure Key Vault Name and Secret Name. How do you provide all this into a value in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it! For anyone looking for the answer, the value needs to be:

```
/subscriptions/[subscription id]/resourceGroups/[rg name]/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/[key vault name]/secrets/[secret name]
```

e.g.

```
/subscriptions/fe7a6c5f-ad2f-4330-bc81-9f93edd3ad17/resourceGroups/test-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/test-kv/secrets/My-Secret
```